# Error: expected expression before 'dadosaluno'

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um programa de cadastramento de alunos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

/*Elabore um programa em linguagem C, que seja capaz registrar um conjunto de dados de uma turma de programação de computadores em memória RAM.
Esta turma possui no máximo 20 alunos.
Cada aluno é representado por uma struct, que é composta por matrícula, nome, nota 1, nota 2 e média.
O conjunto de alunos da turma deve ser estruturado na memória RAM através de um vetor, que será manipulado através das operações
"Incluir aluno", "Excluir aluno", "Consultar aluno", "Listar alunos da turma". Além destas opções, que comporão um menu, também é necessária uma opção para finalizar o programa.*/

typedef struct{
int matricula;
char nome [100];
float n1,n2,media;
}dadosaluno[20];

void incluir(void);
void exlcuir(void);
void consultar(void);
void listar(void);

int main(void){
int i,aux,media;
char opcao;
printf("|=============================================|\n");
printf("|SELECIONE UMA OPCAO|\n");
printf("A->INCLUIR ALUNOS\n");
printf("B->EXCLUIR ALUNOS\n");
printf("C->CONSULTAR ALUNOS\n");
printf("D->LISTAR ALUNOS\n");
printf("E->ENCERRAR O PROGRAMA\n");
printf("|=============================================|");
printf("\nInforme uma opcao(A,B,C,D,E): ");
opcao = getch();
switch(opcao){
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
        incluir();
        break;
    case 'B':
    case 'b':
        excluir();
        break;
    case 'C':
    case 'c':
        consultar();
        break;
    case 'D':
    case 'd':
        listar();
        break;
    case 'E':
    case 'e':
        printf("\n\n*PROGRAMA ENCERRADO*\n\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("\n\n*ESCOLHEU OPCAO INVALIDA*\n\n");
        break;
    }
return 0;
}
void incluir(void){
int i,media = 0,n1 = 0,n2 = 0;
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        printf("\n\nInsira a matricula do aluno: ");
        scanf("%d",&dadosaluno[i].matricula);
        printf("Insira o nome do aluno: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s",&dadosaluno[i].nome);
        printf("Insira a nota 1 do aluno: ");
        scanf("%f",&dadosaluno[i].n1);
        printf("Insira a nota 2 do aluno: ");
        scanf("%f",&dadosaluno[i].n2);
        media = (n1 + n2)/2;
        dadosaluno[i].media = media;
    }
}
void excluir(void){
int i,aux;
printf("Digite a matricula do aluno que deseja excluir: ");
scanf("%d",&aux);
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        if(aux == dadosaluno.matricula[i]){
            memset(&dadosaluno[i].nome,0,sizeof(dadosaluno[i].nome));
            memset(&dadosalun[i].n1,0,sizeof(dadosaluno[i].n1));
            memset(&dadosaluno[i].n2,0,sizeof(dadosaluno[i].n2));
            memset(&dadosaluno[i].media,0,sizeof(dadosaluno[i].media));
            memset(&dadosaluno[i].matricula,0,sizeof(dadosaluno[i].matricula));
        }
    }
}
void consultar(void){
int i,aux;
printf("Digite a matricula do aluno que deseja consultar: ");
scanf("%d",&aux);
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        if(aux == dadosaluno.matricula[i]){
            printf("Matricula do aluno: %d\n",dadosaluno[i].matricula);
            printf("Nome do aluno: %s\n",dadosaluno[i].nome);
            printf("Nota 1 do aluno: %.2f\n",dadosaluno[i].n1);
            printf("Nota 2 do aluno: %.2f\n",dadosaluno[i].n2);
            printf("Media do aluno: %.2f\n",dadosaluno[i].media);
        }
    }
}
void listar(void){
int i,;
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        printf("Matricula do aluno: %d\n",dadosaluno[i].matricula);
        printf("Nome do aluno: %s\n",dadosaluno[i].nome);
        printf("Nota 1 do aluno: %.2f\n",dadosaluno[i].n1);
        printf("Nota 2 do aluno: %.2f\n",dadosaluno[i].n2);
        printf("Media do aluno: %.2f\n",dadosaluno[i].media);
    }
}
```

porém o programa esta retornando o erro:

> error: expected expression before 'dadosaluno'

Comment: Você verificou em qual linha está o erro? O compilador geralmente te diz a linha em que aconteceu o erro. Eu percebi que você usou `dadosaluno.matricula[i]` ao invés de `dadosaluno[i].matricula` duas vezes.

Answer (score 1):

O problema começa logo no primeiro `typedef`:

```
typedef struct{
    int matricula;
    char nome [100];
    float n1,n2,media;
} dadosaluno[20];
//           ^-----
```

Isto não fez o que você imagina. Aqui faz um `typedef` definindo que `dadosaluno` corresponde a um array de 20 estruturas iguais à que foi especificada acima, mas você acabou por não criar nenhum objeto desses. Lembre-se que `typedef` é como que criar um tipo alternativo, mas acaba por não criar variáveis só por si.

Para além disso o `typedef` como um array gera muita confusão, por isso aconselho a seguir o que é normal e fazer apenas um `typedef` para a estrutura e depois criar o array dessas estruturas:

```
typedef struct{
    int matricula;
    char nome [100];
    float n1,n2,media;
} aluno;

aluno dadosaluno[20]; //criação do array de estruturas com 20 elementos
```

Embora não seja muito bom usar variáveis globais, esta é a forma que permite manter o código a funcionar com o que já tem escrito. Atente bem na diferença. Agora tem um `typedef` para dar um nome alternativo à estrutura de `aluno`, e de seguida tem a criação de um array de `20` elementos dessa estrutura.

Só com esta alteração a maior parte dos erros de compilação já desapareceram ficando apenas alguns erros de digitação:

- `if(aux == dadosaluno.matricula[i]){` - o índice ficou no local errado pois deveria ser no `dadosaluno`, assim `if(aux == dadosaluno[i].matricula){`
- `memset(&dadosalun[i].n1,0,sizeof(dadosaluno[i].n1));` - aqui faltou um `o` na palavra `&dadosalun`
- `int i,;` - uma virgula a mais antes do `;`
- `scanf(" %[^\n]s",&dadosaluno[i].nome);` - O `&` está a mais pois o campo `nome` já será interpretado como um ponteiro.

Guiei me apenas pelos erros e avisos de compilação para lhe mostrar os problemas. E é muito importante que faça o mesmo, dando extrema relevância não só aos erros como também aos avisos que são quase sempre erros.

Isto não quer dizer que não tenha mais problemas de lógica mas pelo menos não tem nenhum de compilação.